# codeigniter controller mechanism

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, constructor

my project is using coneigniter, lightweight php framework.
I am a little bit newbie with this.

so, my question is..

this is php file.

```
Actor extends Controller
{
    $a = 0;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = 1;  
    }

    function abc()
    {
        echo $this->a;
    }

}
```

So, when i call the Actor class's function abc() using ajax, 
the constructor, __construct() is called everytime?

I mean... in html file

```
<script>
    $.post(.... , url : "http://someaddress/actor/abc", function result(data){
        alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

result data alert is 1 or 0?

Comment: Bear in mind that when you extend the CodeIgniter Controller class, you'll probably want to call the base class's `__construct()` method in your own constructor, e.g. in your `__construct()`, use `parent::__construct();` to make sure everything's set up properly before your own code.

Comment: Yes this is a good point - @OP read the CI docs - they are literally the best source of information next to SO.

Comment: ah, thanks for your clarifing~ ^^;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused why you don't run this to find out, but yes in principle calling /actor/abc would result in "1".

Likewise:

```
Actor extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "always echo this ";
    }

    function abc()
    {
        echo "only echo this when called ";
    }

    function dosomethingelse()
    {
        //do other stuff
    }

}
```

Will result in "always echo this only echo this when called" when you hit /actor/abc, and if you hit /actor/dosomethingelse just "always echo this" will render.

Read up about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

(edited for bit of clarity)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  A new instance of Actor is created with each new request.  So the constructor of the Controller will be called on each request.  The result will be 1.